# Hair Dynamics do not work on a object that has been parented

Tags: animation, particles, parent, hair

I currently have a sphere parented to a key chain. This sphere has hair particles. Basically, I'm trying to make a pom pom -esq key chain, similar to what Fendi makes. However, when I apply the hair particle effect and turn on hair dynamics, the hair doesn't move in the animation. I have key framed the gold chain [see image] to move, and the ball moves with the gold chain but the hair does not. Any recommendations?

[image: issue 1]

Here is the blender file [image]

Comment: Can you upload your .blend file to [Blend Exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com)?

Comment: Uploaded and added it to the original question!

Comment: Found the problem! Read my answer, where I tell what it was __and__ include a fixed .blend file. If it helps, please consider accepting it by clicking the checkmark in the upper-lefthand corner of my answer. It would help me greatly and make me very happy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wasn't parenting. You need to start the animation on frame 1, rather than frame 38. This allows it to cache from the beginning. I figured it out by rebuilding a .blend file and testing everytime I changed something until I found the issue, which I did.

Here is the fixed (Start 38 --> 1) .blend file.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! However, I still have a bit of an issue because I want the animation to loop perfectly. The reason why I had the animation start at frame 38 is because I wanted the ball to be an the bottom of the swing but still have the hair be in motion. Any recommendations on how I can make it look more like a seamless loop?

Comment: Render 1-end and then play with it in the VSE.